# avascript:history.go(-window.history.length) does not work

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am doing mobile html page via phonegap
I want to redirect user to first page. So I cannot give direct link such as a href to index.html

When User click logo I want to calculate page length that he visited and use `history.go`.

```
 <a href="#" onclick="goBack();return false;" ><img class="main-logo" src="Content/Media/Images/logo.png"></a>


  function goBack() {

var backLength=window.history.length;
    javascript:history.go(-backLength);
}
```

but this does not work, no error but don't redirect

Answer (score 1):

Remove `javascript:` and wrap in script tag:

```
<script>
  function goBack() {
    var backLength=window.history.length;
    history.go(-backLength);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: this does not work: https://hybridsoftware.net/b/BookWithPassengerInfo.htm?guid=8ff6862c-79c5-4a99-8994-0ede54a4a349&leaveCardID=840d66bf-0541-49a1-9570-cbef5812bbd9&DirectionType=1&IsInternational=false#    can you click logo here please,logo has goBack function but it does now work,no error but does not work

Answer (score 0):

**Clean up code. To avoid submit, use `(javascript: void 0)` in href. Use proper callback**

```js
function goBack() {
    console.log("Test")
    var backLength= window.history.length;
   history.go(-backLength);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: void 0" onclick="goBack()" ><img class="main-logo" src="Content/Media/Images/logo.png"></a>
```

Comment: I added your code here,can you click logo please(bilet eviniz),do you see any mistake? it does now work .no error  https://hybridsoftware.net/b/BookWithPassengerInfo.htm?guid=8ff6862c-79c5-4a99-8994-0ede54a4a349&leaveCardID=840d66bf-0541-49a1-9570-cbef5812bbd9&DirectionType=1&IsInternational=false#

Comment: where is goBack function defined ??

Comment: define your goBack() function within a script tag on the same page as the html anchor tag. If the link is in the header code that repeats for each page, put the script tags with the goBack function just after the closing anchor tags ```<a/>```

Comment: you can see it in view source,search function goBack() please..I defined it.That function triggered when I debug it or console.log it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using:

```
window.history.length-1
```